# How to get std::set pointer to the raw data?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I want to pass the whole set as an argument to a function, like the way we do for arrays (i.e &array[0]). I am not able to figure out how to get the pointer to the raw data for a set.

Comment: ... and what is the goal to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do it in the same way as an array because `std::set` is not required to have it's data arranged in a contiguous block of memory. It is a binary tree so it most likely consists of linked nodes. But you can pass it by reference, or use the `begin()` and `end()` iterators.

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const std::set<T>& s);

template <typename Iterator>
void bar(Iterator first, Iterator last);

std::set<int> mySet = ....;
foo(mySet);
bar(mySet.begin(), mySet.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a pointer to the raw data in the same sense as you'd do for an array, because a `set` doesn't reside in continuous memory.

> I want to pass the whole set as an argument to a function

Pass it by reference. There's no memory overhead (if that's what you were worrying about):

```
void foo(std::set<int>& x);
```

Comment: Yes, one of the concerns I had was memory overhead. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to iterate through the `std::set` to extract all the elements of the `std::set`.
Unlike `std::vector` and arrays there is no requirment imposed by the standard that `std::set` elements should be located in contiguos memory.

Either pass an reference/pointer to `std::set` in the function and extract the data inside the function by iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by:

> "I want to pass the whole set as an argument to a function"

```
std::set<int>  data;
// fill data;
```

You can pass the set by reference:

```
plop(data);   // void plop(std::set<int>& data); // passing be reference would be the C++ way
```

Alternatively you can pass iterators.
This abstracts away the type of container you are using and thus allows the writers of plop() to concentrate on the algorithm. In this case the iterators behave in the same way as pointers (in C++ code).

```
plop(data.begin(), data.end(); // template<typename I> void plop(I begin, I end);
```

Alternatively do you mean you want to pass the data in a set to a C like function.
In this case you need to pass a pointer (as that is the only thing C can understand). Unfortunately you can not pass a pointer into a set directly as that has no real meaning. But you can copy the data into a vector and from there into a C program:

```
std::vector<int>  datavec(data.begin(), data.end());
plop(&data[0], datavec.size());   // void plop(int* data, std::size_t size);
```

This works because vector stores the data in contiguous memory.

Comment: Thanks. Vector wouldn't work in my case because the function where I needed to pass the set as an argument had the argument datatype as std::set and I am not allowed to modify that.